# Count numbers of elements that belong to another element in SQL (Number of products per brand)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that displays the number of products that belong to each brand, for example:

```
shoe1 = brand1,
shirt2 = brand1,
pants1 = brand2
shirt1 = brand3
shoe2 = brand3
hat1 = brand3
```

So the query should display:

```
brand1 --> 2,
brand2 --> 1,
brand3 --> 3
```

Sorry if this is confusing I don't really know how to explain it and I'm new to all of this,
Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so in order to help we would need to see the schemas for (I assume) 2 tables involved in this. [Why should I provide an mcve for what seems to me to be a very simple sql query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please provide tables schema and sample data [mre]

Comment: Please do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` on both tables and copy/paste the output to your question

Answer (score 0):

That is a simple `GROUP BY` brand

Assuming your table `tab1` has two columns `product` and `brand`

```
SELECT brand,COUNT(*) as countbrands FROM tab1 GROUP BY brand
```